# vnc4server. Daemon working. autostart not working

Tags: linux, vnc

I have a Parrot OS Linux installed on my raspberry pi 3. I installed a VNC server using `vnc4server` and after some fight with `~/.vnc/xstartup` file is working fine with my xfce4 Desktop Environment:

```
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
startxfce4 &
```

I made a daemon ([here it is](http://pastebin.com/enxL67up)) which is on /etc/init.d and has 755 permissions. The daemon works fine if you execute it manually `/etc/init.d/vncboot start|stop|restart` . Some example output:

```
#/etc/init.d/vncboot restart
Stopping VNC Server
Killing Xvnc4 process ID 6663

Starting VNC Server

New 'station:1 (root)' desktop is station:1

Starting applications specified in /root/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /root/.vnc/station:1.log
```

And after that, I can connect without any problem. I already executed `update-rc.d vncboot enable` in order to try to start this automatically... but the problem is after a reboot, I try to connect to VNC server and some errors appear. Sorry because the errors are in Spanish:

[image: error1]

[image: error2]

Anyway, If I use the daemon `/etc/init.d/vncboot restart` the errors disappear and it works again connecting fine. This is the VNC server log when it has errors on reboot: [Log](http://pastebin.com/6i7U4x63)

Where is my problem? on daemon config? On xserver config? On vncserver config? Even is valid to me the "dirty trick" of automatize a command using the daemon restart on every boot if possible because the daemon makes it work. Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer myself... I found a solution. Maybe useful for others...

I created a script on `/etc/rc5.d` because is the last runlevel to start... and the script was called `S99vncboot`. The 99 is because I want it to be executed in the end. After put it permissions 755 with chmod, the script has this content:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30
/etc/init.d/vncboot restart
```

With this, the daemon is restarted after reboot and after 30 seconds... which made it work.